# Metalic textures not rendering

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I have a problem with eevee render: it shows the metal reflections in the viewport but not in the final render. What is wrong?

[image]

[image]

---

Moving the camera away helps, but the metal on the object still has no reflection maybe I should have an background image to reflect something...

[image]

---

This changes not much. I post my shader settings I followed in a tutorial earlier maybe the problem is there.

[image]

Comment: Hey :). There seems to be *some* reflection. Perhaps move your camera a bit farther to see more of it.

Comment: To get similar reflections as in your viewport, use HDRI as environment texture :).

Answer (score 0):

Yes,I feel nothing to reflect might be your problem.

You can use an HDR to check reflections and lightings. Just a google search would help, or just go to https://hdrihaven.com/ or http://www.hdrlabs.com/sibl/archive.html

You can get some free HDR and just plug the .exr into "world" shader-node.

This would solve issues if some are there with your scene itself.

You can also try checking the screen-space reflections box in the render options. Might help. I would uncheck half-res to hoping that no half-res makes it full-res.

[image: Screen space reflections]